# Bind an object to a Symfony form

Tags: symfony

I have a entity with some data prefilled, and I want to display them on the form : here state would be `ACTIVE` and `customerId = 1`;

```
// Form file (ben.file.create)
protected function buildForm()
{
    $this->formBuilder->add('name', 'text', ['label'=>'Nom du patient'])
        ->add('customerId', 'integer')
        ->add('state', 'choice', ['choices'=>['ACTIVE'=>'ACTIVE',
            'DONE'=>'DONE', 'CANCELLED'=>'CANCELLED']]);

}


// in the controller
public function index()
{
    $form = $this->createForm("ben-file-create");

    $file = new BenFile();
    $file->setCustomerId(1);
    $file->setState('ACTIVE');

    $form->getForm()->submit($file); // <--- Here the glue problem
    return $this->render('create-file', array());
}
```

It looks like `submit` is not the right bind function. I would expect that the form is pre-filled accordingly, and after the POST request, I have an updated BenFile entity.

Comment: Also you can set those values at the BenFile constructor, so the form will be rendered with active state, supposing his state would be always active at first, probably CustomerId is the value of the logged user?

Answer (score 1):

You can do easily in createForm method :

```
// in the controller
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $file = new BenFile();
    $file->setCustomerId(1);
    $file->setState('ACTIVE');

    $form = $this->createForm("ben-file-create", $file);

    // handle submit
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // flush entity 
        $fileNew = $form->getData();

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($fileNew );
        $entityManager->flush();
    }

    return $this->render('create-file', array());
}
```